# sivs R package Error in apply(coef.df, 1, function(f) { : dim(X) must have a positive length

Tags: r, error-handling, apply, r-package

In the documentation of sivs the example looks like this:

```
***sivs_obj <- sivs(x = tmp[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
                             "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")],
                 y = factor(tmp$Species),
                 family = "binomial",
                 verbose = "detailed",
                 progressbar = FALSE,
                 nfolds = 3,
                 parallel.cores = FALSE,
                 iter.count = 20)***
```

I've followed it like this:

```
***sivs_obj <- sivs(x=sx, y=factor(xql.eff$effect_mu), family = "binomial")***
```

and it gives me this error:

```
***Error in apply(coef.df, 1, function(f) { : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length***
```

which I looked up, and I found that the problem is that the apply gets a vector instead of matrix or dataframe. I guess that vector is the y. But the documentation example uses vector aswell (at least I think). What can I do? Or could somebody tell me what is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

SIVS developer here. Thanks for using our software. Yesterday I got an email from another user about this, and he today pointed me to this SO post. Also yesterday I made a post about this with enough details to explain the issue:

https://github.com/mmahmoudian/sivs/issues/2

Considering that this is a very rare case, I haven't been able to reproduce this on any data. Therefore there is no way for me to investigate this. Please contact me via email (email can be found in [the CRAN page of the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sivs/)) and if possible please provide a sample data (if it is not confidential) so that I can investigate this further.

For the time being, I can only give you these suggestions:

1. try removing samples (rows) that have identical values across all features.

   ```r
   DATA <- DATA[apply(DATA, 1, function(i){ length(unique(i)) != 1 }), ]
   ```

   if you have so many of such samples, glmnet would have very hard time to converge.
2. try removing features that are identical or have correlation == 1
3. try setting the `alpha` argument to something lower than 1, e.g 0.8. `sivs::siv()` passes extra arguments to the underlying method, so just add `alpha = 0.8` to your sivs call.

Please note that none of the above is a definitive answer, I'm just blindly speculating about this as there is no way to investigate this further without running it on the data.